# iOS NSUserDefaults not working if upgrade the app from ios 9 to ios 10

Tags: ios, xcode, nsuserdefaults, code-signing-entitlements

I had an app running on iOS 9 and I created a new build for iOS 10 with Xcode 8 beta 4, now when I upgrade the app from previous version (iOS 9) to the new version (iOS 10) in this scenario...

Install the previous version with Xcode 7 on an iPhone (with ios 9 or 10) then kill the app and install the new version with Xcode 8 beta 4 on the same device it treats the upgrade as a new install so all of the NSUserDefaults saved values return nil!

I tested a sample app and followed the scenarios there was no problem with `NSUserDefaults` in this case as I used `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]` to save and retrieve the values but in the following implementation which has problem its using a shared container to save data, I believe "entitlementGroup" causing the issue!

SDK 10 might not be able to recognize the previously created shared container by SDK 9! Is there any thought on that? The problem is I cannot fix the code by replacing `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]` instead of using entitlementGroup because users currently using the previous version of the app and any change to the new version doesn't fix the issue as it requires to be fixed in two versions.

Here is main parts of the code (written by previous developer):

```
@implementation AppDelegate

-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState] == UIApplicationStateBackground) { 

    // background launch

} else {

    //foreground launch 

    [self setupForForegroundLaunch:application option:launchOptions];

    [[TrackingManager sharedTrackingManager] setIsBackground:NO];

}

}

@end
```

Comment: You have new simulated iOS 10 devices with Xcode 8, so when you run on those devices it is as if the app was just installed.

Comment: Yes true but real devices have same problem. If I have already old version of the app installed on my phone with ios 8 or 9 and then if I upgrade to the new version of the app which has developed with xcode 8 all saved NSUserDefaults values return nil. The way that I test it is: I install the old version of the app with xcode 7 and then kill the app and install the new version with xcode 8 on the iPhone. Some previously saved user's settings gone and treat the app as a new install! It happens on all ios 8-10 devices

Comment: I just created a simple test project that sets a NSUserDefaults value if it is nil or prints it if it is present.  I ran it under Xcode 7.3 on an iOS 9.3.4 device and it created the default.  A second run printed the default value as expected.  I then ran the project under Xcode 8b3 and it printed the default value as expected.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, so in this case I think I need to find the reason causing this issue somewhere in the project.

Comment: The first thing to check is that the bundle Id doesn't change

Comment: and did you create the sample code with sdk 9 and then migrated to sdk 10 and upgraded the app?

Comment: I created the project in Xcode 7 and then loaded it into Xcode 8. I set the Swift build setting for swift 2

Comment: The bundle Id is same for both scenario, I was thinking to use the shared NSFileManager directory instead of NSUserDefaults as I have no clue how to fix the NSUserDefaults issue

Comment: I also tried after upgrading the project to Swift 3 syntax and had no problem.  Perhaps you can show the code where you set and read the defaults

Comment: Please see the updated question. I created a sample code too and I ended up that NSUserDefault doesn't have problem I explained above.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that sdk 10 doesn't cause any issue with NSUserDefaults.

It was only ordering issue in the project, in `AppDelegate` I was calling `[[TrackingManager sharedTrackingManager] setIsBackground:NO];` before this line `[self setupForForegroundLaunch:application option:launchOptions];`

While I generally have initialized the Entitlement_Group in `setupForForegroundLaunch` function and in singleton of `TrackingManager` class also Entitlement_Group gets initiated with nil value which this caused the issue I only changed the order of these two line and now everything is working well.

Answer (score -1):

Incase of change in entitlement file cause such kind of issues.Please refer the following links.

[AboutEntitlements](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/AboutEntitlements.html)